# did you register the component correctly? For recursive components

Tags: vue.js, components

maybe someone can help me, i have a problem, i try to make component with vue like this

```
Vue.component('product-list', {
   
    props: ['product'],

    template : `<h1>{{this.product}}</h1>`
}),
```

and i call the component in index.html like this

```
<product-list :product="'This Product List'"></product-list>
```

and result is eror like this

[eror massage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yy9DX.png)

learn to make a component header with vue

Comment: It's unknown how exactly you do this. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. You can use SO snippet functionality for a workable demo